# Why does numpy module fail in genpy?

Tags: python, numpy, package, pycharm, geany

I did all the downloads, I checked, but I couldn't figure out why geany gave an error. Works in Pycharm, no module error[Downloads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f3SF.png)
[Genpy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwyEU.png)[Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmjDf.png)

I installed numpy as a package from settings in pycharm. It was installed to python310 folder with pip install numpy but it didn't work in geany

Comment: Try again after reinstalling numpy with powershell or cmd. pip uninstall numpy and them pip install numpy

Comment: I did, nothing changed

Comment: Is this the editor `geany` (using its `terminal` window)?  I use that some.  What's `genpy`?  What operating system?   What pip installation directories?

Comment: You need to figure out the 'python-path' is for your `geany` terminal.  It must not be looking in the same `3.10` `site_packages` as pycharm.

Comment: Look at `os.environ` (need to import os) on the sytem that works and the one that doesn't.  The `PATH` is particularly important when it comes to importing packages like `numpy`.

Comment: I wrote genpy instead of geany.Sorry about that.This is c:\users\mertk\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages directory.This is the compile code on geany: py -m py_compile "%f"   and execute code on geany:py "%f"

Comment: When I print this code: print(os.environ) I get folllowing(
I delete the parts that didn't work)C:\\Users\\mertk\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\;C:\\Users\\mertk\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\;bin;C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3\\bin;'''C:\\Users\\Public', 'PYCHARM COMMUNITY EDITION': 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3\\bin;
(When I print this code on geany: print("\n" + sys.version) I get the following
3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: Actually, when I installed numpy with pip, pycharm didn't work either, but I did it from the settings section. In Geany, there is no place like pycharm where you can install the package. The path part ends the event as you said. Geany can't find the Package

Comment: I looked again at your geany png image.  Looks like a generic `cmd.exe` terminal window  (before I thought you were using a 'terminal' in the status bar, which is hard to setup in windows).  On my `miniconda` installation, I have to use a special `Anaconda` terminal shortcut, which has the necessary PATH etc setup.  My generic terminal can't even access Python.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found why it is giving error.hpauljAs he said, it is related to path.First run this: import sys  print(sys.executable).  I had this result: C:\Users\mertk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
But when I say pip install numpy, it directs to C:\Users\mertk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib/site-packages( 1.24.3)

so  I install numpy to python311 with directly and I got new error when compile code again on geany[Python311](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wisnu.png)[NewError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkb3v.png)
Previously it was giving module not found error, now it gives this error. After adding numpy to the Python 311 folder